# Append html to div

Tags: javascript

I want to add custom html to a div using this function in the functions.php file. I'm not sure why this isn't working.

```
function add_html_under_div() {
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">

          // create a new div element
          const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
          newDiv.innerHTML = '<a>test</a>';

          //div
          var description_div = document.querySelector('.description_div');

          // add newDiv under description_div
          description_div.appendChild(newDiv);
        </script>
    <?php
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_html_under_div');
```

Am I not getting the description_div the right way?

Any help is much appriciated!

Comment: Your JavaScript is in the header and is running as soon as the script tag is loading so the div you're looking for won't exist yet when the script runs. You should run your script in the footer or inside an event listener that runs page load. Note that this is all pure JavaScript advice and WordPress is not really relevant.

Comment: remember, the page doesn't load in all at once in a single step, it loads in piece by piece from the top to the bottom. You could be reading part of the page before the footer tags have been generated on the server side if it takes a while to load. Wait until the page indicates it's ready before doing this kind of thing, but also keep in mind generic JS questions are better on stackoverflow